# using mongodb and express , i created a crud api for a taskmanager app,but getting error in dispalying it using fetch api method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dom, fetch-api

in fetch api method ,for each loop is throwing error
it seeems json data in api in which for each method is not applicable.pls help

```
const postslist = document.querySelector('postslist')

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(task => {
        console.log(task)
        postslist.innerHTML += `
       <div class="card">
       <h3>${task.name}</h3>
       
            <button class="Edit-btn">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
       </div>
      `

    } )
  })
```

Comment: You might add your backend code as well. Because this frontend seems okay.

Comment: @MithatErcan I made my api thorough backend only and there crud operation is performed smoothly.error is with frontend only.should i share the code?

Comment: Without knowing what `/api/v1/tasks` endpoint does, we can't guess the error.

Comment: {
"task": [
{
"_id": "63a1d181a5051901ed6b50b5",
"name": "secondtasks",
"completed": false,
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "63a1d18ca5051901ed6b50b7",
"name": "secondtask",
"completed": true,
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "63a218369c062cfdc74823e5",
"name": "Brush teeth",
"completed": false,
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "63a21c69d6ad76e64d4e8174",
"name": "Brush teeth",
"completed": false,
"__v": 0
}
]
}

Comment: this is the api which in json form  ,/api/v1/tasks

Comment: Edit your post and add your code there, not here as a comment.

Comment: i am getting errors,can u share any taskmanager app code? pls

Comment: Is the response from 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks' an array or an object?  You may just need to use `data.task.forEach(....`